# how to integrate multiple machines as one system?

Tags: batch, cluster

As the title. What I wish to get from this is:
1. the four nodes works like only one computer, i.e., one root, one system, one bash, one updates for all machines.
2. once a user is logged in, it is able to access the harddrive and cores in all nodes.

here are more information about my situation:

1. We have four nodes (Ubuntu installed), each of them have multiple cores. So far all of them are identical, but maybe later on more nodes will be added with different hardwares.
2. We usually use these nodes to conduction scientific computations. At the moment each of them are working individually. There are about 10 people using these resources.
3. I have learned by googling that [Single System Image (SSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image) can be one of the solutions. However, the packages listed in the wiki page seem not updating for quite a while (e.g., the latest release of [openSSI](http://openssi.org/cgi-bin/view?page=openssi.html) was 2010) and there are not so much step-by-step tutorials for the setup on the web, which give me a feeling that this is an old-fashioned solution. So if this could be a good solution based on your experience, which software on the package list or tutorials on the web could make a go as a start?
4. Currently there is a cluster in our uni using batch system to manage all the runs. But for us it may not be necessary to do it so far, as there are only few users and limited simulation runs. Considering the potential of having more users in the following two years, and the possible hardware upgrade, do you think installing batch system would be the ultimate (or the convinent) solution? at least all the abovementioned criteras can be satisfied?

Your reply is appreciated.

Comment: Would [PXE boot and NFS root](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) suffice? You could try SSI, [Mosix](http://www.mosix.com) is still updated and is available for the 3.14 kernel.